# Laravel HTTP Client send headers, params, raw body as json does not work

Tags: laravel, guzzle, laravel-8

I want to call an api and I have some headers, path variables and a json raw body to send over post method. First I tried this:

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Api-Key' => env('CLIENT_API_KEY'),
])
->post(env('API_ROOT_URL').'/my/api/url/'.$path_variable, [
    'raw_body_0' => $raw_0,
    'raw_body_1' => $raw_1,
]);
```

And

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Api-Key' => env('CLIENT_API_KEY'),
])
->post(env('API_ROOT_URL').'/my/api/url', [
    'path_variable' => $path_variable,
    'raw_body_0' => $raw_0,
    'raw_body_1' => $raw_1,
]);
```

And `$response->successful()` return `false`. Next tried:

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Api-Key' => env('CLIENT_API_KEY'),
])
->withBody(json_encode([
    'raw_body_0' => $raw_0,
    'raw_body_1' => $raw_1,
]), 'json')
->post(env('API_ROOT_URL').'/my/api/url/'.$path_variable);
```

And

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Api-Key' => env('CLIENT_API_KEY'),
])
->withBody(json_encode([
    'raw_body_0' => $raw_0,
    'raw_body_1' => $raw_1,
]), 'json')
->post(env('API_ROOT_URL').'/my/api/url', [
    'path_variable' => $path_variable,
]);
```

And again no success.

**NOTE** that `env('CLIENT_API_KEY')` and `env('API_ROOT_URL')` work great with simple requests with no raw body or with no combination of parameters that I should send. my api is over HTTPS which again works great with other requests. I also tried header `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'` and when I send the request with postman, it works fine.

What's the problem? How can I do this?

Comment: Try to send a request using [`asJson`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L166) method.

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev No luck with `asJson()`

Comment: try to write the whole code in try catch & catch the RequestException, you can log it will tell you the reason why $response->successful() return false, Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException

Comment: of the methods you have written first should work, 2nd one & 4th one looks incorrect

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have send by following code

```
 $param['Vehicles']   = "LEA-2255";       
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token
        ])->withBody(json_encode($param),'application/json')->get('http://sellme.pk/');
```

Comment: Looks correct and it should work. Referenced from laravel 8.x  [sending-a-raw-request-body](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#sending-a-raw-request-body)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
   'Api-Key' => env('CLIENT_API_KEY'),
])
->send('POST', env('API_ROOT_URL') . '/my/api/url/' . $path_variable, [
   'body' => '{
                "raw_body_0":"' . $raw_0 . '",
                "raw_body_1":"' . $raw_1 . '",
              }'
])->json();
```

or this one,

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
   'Api-Key' => env('CLIENT_API_KEY'),
])
->send('POST', env('API_ROOT_URL') . '/my/api/url/' . $path_variable, [
   'body' => json_encode([
                'raw_body_0' => $raw_0,
                'raw_body_1' => $raw_1,
            ])
])->json();
```